# Unable to hide elements from CSS using ASP.NET4

Tags: .net, css, asp.net-4.0

i am unable to hide my asp:buttons from CSS. i am using ASP.NET 4

CSS

```
.SiteButton
{
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

HTML

```
<asp:Button ID="btnFromCalOpen" runat="server" Text=" &gt; " class = "siteButton"   />
```

Please Help

Comment: be sure to use the green checkmark to mark the answer that helped you out the most to answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `class="siteButton"` to `CssClass="SiteButton"`

CSS is case-sensitive for class names and `siteButton` is different from `SiteButton`.

Also in ASP.NET the class is set by `CssClass` rather than `class`, however class will still work since ASP.NET will pass through unknown properties to the browser.

Comment: ASP.NET does not recognize the `class` attribute on its controls. Have an upvote anyhow :)

Comment: ASP.NET won't recognize `class` but it will send it to the browser still. It won't let you change it programatically of course.